# Adding Liquidity to Ropsten RPC Error: execution reverted: TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, metamask

I deployed a smart contract on Ropsten, all functions seem to work fine, however I cant seem to add Liquidity, I am doing it via the UI on https://app.uniswap.org/#/add/ETH/

Im getting in my console log, RPC Error: execution reverted: TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED

I have manually approved my tokens, yet I still receive the error, what might the issue be?

Comment: So you deployed an ERC-20 token contract, is that correct? Did you create an exchange contract for your token (with another token, e.g. WETH)? You'll need to do that before you can supply liquidity to it. Since you're the first liquidity provider, you'll need to provide both sides of the pool to set the initial price. It sounds like maybe you haven't approved uniswap to take both your token and the other token.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem.